# Как работать с подзапросом который возвращает множество строк

Tags: sql

У меня есть следующий запрос:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `a` WHERE ab = ( SELECT `id` FROM `c` WHERE `active` = 1 )
```

Ошибка:
Підзапит повертає більш нiж 1 запис(Подзапрос возвращает больше чем 1 запись)

Что требуется:
У меня есть две таблицы `a` и `b`, мне требуется получить `id` из таблицы `a` в случае если в `ab` указаны `id` из таблицы `c`, но при этом те `id` из таблицы `c` в которых в колонке `active` указана `1`

Скорее всего объяснил ужасно, но буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: ```... WHERE ab IN (SELECT ...``` либо ```... WHERE ab = ANY (SELECT ...``` (можно и SOME). PS. Колонка-то одна - а вот записей больше одной.

Comment: @Akina Cпасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проверить вхождение значения поля в список значений используй IN:

```
SELECT id
FROM a
WHERE ab IN (SELECT id FROM c WHERE active = 1)
```